Apache Batik Script Evaluation
I've created the following code as a test of Batik's Rhino integration:
public class BatikTest
{
        public static void main(String...args) throws SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException, TranscoderException, TransformerException
        {
                SAXSVGDocumentFactory factory = new SAXSVGDocumentFactory(XMLResourceDescriptor.getXMLParserClassName());
                Document document = factory.createSVGDocument(null, new StringReader("<svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\"><script>java.lang.System.out.println('Hello, World!');</script></svg>"));
                TranscoderInput input = new TranscoderInput(document);
                ImageTranscoder transcoder = new ImageTranscoder()
                {
                        private BufferedImage image;

                        @Override
                        public BufferedImage createImage(int width, int height) {
                                return new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void writeImage(BufferedImage image, TranscoderOutput output) throws TranscoderException {
                                this.image = image;

                        }};
                StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
                transcoder.transcode(input, null);
                DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
                StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
                TransformerFactory factori = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                Transformer transformer = factori.newTransformer();
                transformer.transform(source, result);
                System.out.println(writer.toString());
        }
}

Why isn't the string "Hello, World!" printing to console? What am I missing?

That is correct, but the Rhino implementation that Batik uses allows you to reference java objects/code with functions such as importClass importPackage, etc. Read the section labelled Rhino Features
